# Postgresql GIN index on jsonb strange behaviour

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

I'm using `postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.5 (Homebrew)` on Mac OS X 12.6.

Here is my table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test1 (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  data JSONB,
  column1 VARCHAR
);

CREATE INDEX ON test1 USING GIN (data);
```

Now if I filter the records using this query

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE data @> '"foo"';
```

I can see that the GIN index has been used:

```
                                 QUERY PLAN                                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on test1  (cost=8.07..18.22 rows=8 width=68)
   Recheck Cond: (data @> '"foo"'::jsonb)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test1_data_idx  (cost=0.00..8.06 rows=8 width=0)
         Index Cond: (data @> '"foo"'::jsonb)
```

If now I create the same table but with some more columns like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test2 (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  data JSONB,
  column1 VARCHAR,
  column2 VARCHAR,
  column3 VARCHAR
);

CREATE INDEX ON test2 USING GIN (data);
```

and perform the same query

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE data @> '"foo"';
```

I see that the GIN index is no more used:

```
                       QUERY PLAN                       
--------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on test2  (cost=0.00..16.38 rows=5 width=132)
   Filter: (data @> '"foo"'::jsonb)
```

Why does this happen? How can I get around this problem?

Comment: Looks like the table is empty, that makes a sequential read the fastest solution. Could you share the result from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) ? The difference could an auto analyze that ran between your first and second attempt.

Comment: QUERY PLAN                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on public.test2  (cost=0.00..16.38 rows=5 width=132) (actual time=0.011..0.013 rows=4 loops=1)
   Output: id, data, column1, column2, column3
   Filter: (test2.data @> '"foo"'::jsonb)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1
   Buffers: shared hit=1
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=1
 Planning Time: 0.081 ms
 Execution Time: 0.026 ms

Comment: rows=4, that's within my definition of "empty". And this, Execution Time: 0.026 ms , how could an index improve the performance? That's 26 microseconds

Comment: I've filled the table with 1 million records. Now the index is used. 